# unable to connect to a certain website

Tags: webserver, proxy, browser

I am currently developing a website for a client, I uploaded the web site files using an FTP client (filezilla), and I got a connection timeout during the upload, ever since then I couldn't access the web site either through a browser or through the FTP client, I cannot ping the web as well (RTO)

Is it possible that I or my IP was banned by the web server since I can still access the web anywhere else but from my house.

If that's so, then can I do something beside contacting the server's admin because I am actually outsourced by the client and it seems that they won't give any access regarding this.

Comment: Try `tracert <websiteaddress>` to see at which point you are blocked

Answer (score 2):

**Yes it is possible ;)**

Just contact the server admin / client.  Servers come with firewalls, servers go down.  It is too hard to tell what happened here, your best guess and assessment is what could have happened.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably on the right track with the IP ban by the sound of it. If the server is still accepting FTP connections, just not from your IP, it's pretty cut and dried.

The real issue is...why were you banned?

Most autoban utilities unban an IP address after 1-3 days, so you can maybe just wait it out. If you were auto-banned, the likely reason for that would be failed authentication. Check your filezilla install, account setup and maybe even try a different client.

It's really hard to troubleshoot something like this without any visibility of the other end of the connection.

The best thing to do is to just contact the client. Let them know the situation (ie there is a problem with the configuration of their server) and have them contact the server admin. So long as they let them know that you are the person to deal with, you should be able to thereafter deal with them directly and not have to worry your client any further.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what ISP you have but if you have Comcast Business then you'll want to make sure that you have the [Disable Gateway Smart Packet Detection](http://ckdake.com/content/2008/disable-gateway-smart-packet-detection.html) box checked.  That page describes the issue in more detail.  But it normally manifests itself as a routing issue to one ip or website.

Comment: Awesome, this fixed my sporadic issues connecting to miscellaneous sites from my home net connection!